# Inoke Javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call javascript file from main html page inside ASP.NET, but nothing happens.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>METANIT.COM</title>
    <script type="application/json" src="..html/multScript.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello ASP.NET Core!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var f = function test(a, b) {
    return console.log(a * b)
    //    return a * b
}
f(1, 2)
```

Console is empty.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that ..html/multScript.js is the correct path? check your console errors and network tab of the dev tools

Comment: Looks like src is missing a forward slash  `../html`

Answer (score 0):

Path looks wrong. Likely should be ../html etc.

Comment: "Likely should be ../html etc." - but is it not the same in my path src="..html/multScript.js" ?

Comment: index.html and multScript.js are in the same project folder "html". Browser console shows nothing

Comment: You're not understanding the ".." syntax correctly. ".." means to jump up a layer in the folder hierarchy. You're missing a "/". It should be "../html" not "..html". Unless your folder is called "..html" which is highly unlikely.